# Login error user not activated

Tags: authentication, joomla, mysql-error-1064, backend

I use joomla 1.5.25 had some registered users and admins on the site. a few days ago I put new user registration activation to YES and have jwlogin module as login to front end.

The problem is now Admins can't login to backend error message: `administrator/index.php?option=com_jwuser&view=error&error=User%20is%20not%20activated`

How do I activate Super Admin? Is this possible in MySQL database?
Neither front or backend logins are working.

Answer (score 0):

That should have affected existing users at all. Turning activation one means that the user must click the activation link in the email before their account is active. When it is off, accounts are automatically activated when they are created.

You can look in jos_users table at the `block` and `activation` fields. Block should be 0 and activation should be empty.